# How to make a certain folder to be excluded by McAfee

Tags: exclude, exceptions

In KasperSky I can make an exception for a specific program/folder... with the 'Trusted Zone' feature.

But not in McAfee, I can only make exceptions file by file, which mean you have to add to the exception list 1000 times if there were 1000 files in the folder.

Is there anyway to achieve this?

My version : McAfee LiveSafe 16.0

Comment: [It certainly seems possible.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXJpd.png)

Comment: @Ramhound that is not LiveSafe 16.0

Comment: and btw the image is about schedule scan, what I want is real-time scan.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77219/discussion-between-ramhound-and-eagertolearn).